# PHP - foreach loop in array for generating a json file

Tags: php, arrays, json

Sorry, but I'm quite new to this.

I would like to achieve the following JSON code:

```
"commodities": [
    {
        "originCountryCode": "NL",
        "goodsDescription": "Commodity goods description ",
        "goodsValue": {
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "monetaryValue": 250
        }
    }
```

How can I make goodsValue a part of commodities?
I've tried the following but I can't get it done.

```
$commodities = array();
$commoditie = array();
$goodsValue = array();
$commoditie["originCountryCode"] = "NL";
$commoditie["goodsDescription"] = "Electronics, ".$producten."";
array_push($commodities, $commoditie);
$goodsValue["currencyCode"] = "EUR";
$goodsValue["monetaryValue"] = "".$subtotaal."";
array_push($commodities, $goodsValue);
$data["commodities"] = $commodities;
```

Comment: How do you want the final data to appear.

Comment: could u write down your original data format? the code here is not easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

`How can I make 3 arrays into one and get "packages" into an object?`

```
<?php
$response = array(); 
$response["code"] = 200;
$packages = array();

for ($i=0; $i < 3; $i++) { 
  $package = array(); 
  $package["grossWeight"] = $i;
  $package["scannedBy"] = "someone";
  array_push($packages, $package); // push it to packages array
}
$response["packages"] = $packages; // packages
echo json_encode($response);
```

Result will be

[image]